# Python: Element-wise multiplication of 3d with 3d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, performance, coding-efficiency

I am having some problems implementing the following equation in a performant way using Python:

[image: Equation]

beta and gamma are cartesian coordinates {x,y} and b,m are some index value which can be quite big n=10000. I have a working version of the code which is shown below for the simple case of l=2 and m,b = 4 (l and m always have the same length). I checked the code using timeit and the the bottleneck is the element-wise multiplication with an array of size (3,3) and the reshaping of the resulting array into shape (3m,3m).
Does anybody has an idea how to increase the performance? (I also noticed that my current version suffers a quite big overhead for large values of l....)

```
import numpy as np 

g_l3 = np.array([[1, 4, 5],[2, 6, 7]])
g_l33  = g_l3.reshape(-1, 3, 1) * g_l3.reshape(-1, 1, 3)

A_lm = np.arange(1, 9, 1).reshape(2, 4)
B_lb = np.arange(7, 15, 1).reshape(2, 4)

AB_lmb = A_lm.reshape(-1, 4, 1) * B_lb.reshape(-1, 1, 4)

D_lmb33 = np.sum(g_l33.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 3, 3) * AB_lmb.reshape(-1, 4, 4, 1, 1), axis=0)
D = np.concatenate(np.concatenate(D_lmb33, axis=2), axis=0)
```

Comment: `numpy.reshape` takes almost no time.  It doesn't make any real changes to the data, it just reinterprets the buffers that are already there.  And your `g_l33` is not element-wise multiplication -- that's doing a matrix multiply.  The result is 2x3x3.  Is that what you expect?

Comment: The current code is fast: it takes about 0.025 ms on my machine. I do not understand the case that could be slow (I should help to provide a case where the chosen parameter results in a slow execution). I also did not understand the source of `(3m,3m)` (which does not appear in the code).

Comment: All of your multiplies are matrix multiplies.  You're going to end up with a (3m)**2 array.  If `m` is of any size at all, that's going to really big.

Comment: I am not sure, but the formula looks to me like a einsum. Something like `np.einsum('lg,lb,lmb,lxb->xmbg',g_l_gamma,g_l_beta,A_l_m_beta,B_l_b_beta,optimize='optimal')` (b is replaced by x). But that is not what you do in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [387]: %%timeit
     ...: g_l3 = np.array([[1, 4, 5],[2, 6, 7]])
     ...
     ...: D_lmb33 = np.sum(g_l33.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 3, 3) * AB_lmb.reshape(-1, 4,
     ...:  4, 1, 1), axis=0)
     ...: D = np.concatenate(np.concatenate(D_lmb33, axis=2), axis=0)
     ...: 
     ...: 
70.7 µs ± 226 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Examining the pieces, and rewriting the reshape with `newaxis`, which is visually clearer to me - though basically the same speed:

```
In [388]: g_l3.shape
Out[388]: (2, 3)
In [389]: g_l33.shape
Out[389]: (2, 3, 3)
In [390]: np.allclose(g_l33, g_l3[:,:,None]*g_l3[:,None,:])
Out[390]: True
In [391]: AB_lmb.shape
Out[391]: (2, 4, 4)
In [392]: np.allclose(AB_lmb, A_lm[:,:,None]*B_lb[:,None,:])
Out[392]: True
```

So these the common `outer` products on the last dimension of 2d arrays.

And another `outer`,

```
In [393]: temp=g_l33.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 3, 3) * AB_lmb.reshape(-1, 4, 4, 1, 1)
In [394]: temp.shape
Out[394]: (2, 4, 4, 3, 3)
In [396]: np.allclose(temp, g_l33[:,None,None,:,:] * AB_lmb[:, :,:, None,None])
Out[396]: True
```

These probably could be combined into one expression, but that's not necessary.

`D_lmb33` sums on the leading dimension:

```
In [405]: D_lmb33.shape
Out[405]: (4, 4, 3, 3)
```

the double concatenate can also be done with a transpose and reshape:

```
In [406]: np.allclose(D_lmb33.transpose(1,2,0,3).reshape(12,12),D)
Out[406]: True
```

Overall your code appears to make efficient use of the `numpy`.  For a large leading dimension that `(N,4,4,3,3)` intermediate array could be large, and take time.  But within `numpy` itself there isn't an alternative.  I don't think the algebra allows us to do the sum earlier.  Using `numba` or `numexpr` another question.